# VBA userform message box

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following code for a message box

```
'Message box to ensure that the accounting format equals the loan withdrawl country
If txtloanwithcountry = "England" Then
NumberFormat = "_(£* #,##0.00_);_(£* (#,##0.00);_(£* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

Else

MsgBox "The currency used in the loan withdrawl country must be equal to number format"
End If
```

However, I was wondering how I can input all the countries that uses British Pounds, so when I either type in Wales, Scotland, Nothern-Ireland or England, the Number Format is British Pounds? When I type in other countries, the message box shows. I have tried to use Or Statement, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where does the list of countries reside?

Comment: When you say your tried to use an Or statement but it didn't work, what did the Or statement look like (as that should have worked)?

Comment: I have not created a list of countries, as this is to be typed into the textbox.

Comment: Then I had: If txtloanwithcountry = "England Or Scotland Or Wales Or Northern-Ireland" Then

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to include what you've tried. FWIW all VBA is seeing with that expression is `If txtloadwithcountry = "some rather long string"`.

Comment: If you're going to do this with multiple formats/countries, then I would recommend looking up [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an `Or` you need to include the whole comparison. So it would look like

```
If txtLoanWithCountry = "England" Or txtLoanWithCountry = "Scotland" or txtLoanWithCountry = "Wales" Then
```

Another method is to create an array, then use the Filter function to see if your country is in the array. If Filter returns a Ubound of -1, it didn't find a match.

```
Dim vaPounds As Variant

'Create the array of countries
vaPounds = Split("England Northern-Ireland Scotland Wales")

If UBound(Filter(vaPounds, txtLoanWithCountry)) = -1 Then
    MsgBox "The currency used in the loan withdrawl country must be equal to number format"
Else
    NumberFormat = "_(£* #,##0.00_);_(£* (#,##0.00);_(£* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End If
```